# OAF Advanced table loads slowly

Tags: oracle-adf, oaf

I have a page with an advanced table and some search criteria. On `processRequest()` I call a method where I compose a where clause from the search criteria and call `executeQuery()` on the table's view object. The problem is that this last call takes a long time while in OAF Developer's Guide they write:

> The table rendering logic brings in only the rows you need in an
> incremental fashion. In other words, if your table display size is 10
> rows, then only the first 10 rows from the query are brought in to the
> middle-tier.

What am I doing wrong? How to make the table to load in incremental fashion?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `executeQuery()` with `setPreparedForExecution(true)`.

The table is indeed smart, but you should actually leave the view object's execution to it instead of doing it manually. If you do the suggested replacement, the table will execute the view object automatically at the moment of rendering in incremental fashion.